# Using imported Excel Series to plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I have code that iterates through each graph in a certain excel sheet, the code spits out the series of each graph. Is there a way to use these series to plot them in matplotlib?

```
def series_output(chart):
    print(f'\tChart name is {chart.Name}')
    for sc in chart.SeriesCollection():
        series = sc.Formula
        print(series)
       
            
xl = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(ef)
sh = wb.Sheets('Calc Tool')  
print(f'Processed sheet {sh.Name}')
for ch in sh.ChartObjects():
    series_output(ch.Chart)
    print('*********************')
    print('                     ')
wb.Close(False)  # don't save & close workbook
xl.Quit()
```

Example output: =SERIES('Ensemble L'!$Q$11,'Ensemble L'!$C$12:$C$63,'Ensemble L'!$Q$12:$Q$63,5)

Comment: You need to parse the series formula to then grab the actual values from the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def series_output(chart):
    print(f'\tChart name is {chart.Name}')
    for sc in chart.SeriesCollection():
        series = sc.Formula
        print(series)
        # Extract data range and values from the series formula
        match = re.search(r"SERIES\('.+?'\!(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),\d+\)", series)
        if match:
            data_range = match.group(2)
            data_values = match.group(3)
            # Process the data range and values to convert them to appropriate formats
            # You may need to adjust this part based on the specific format of your data
            x_values = [float(x.strip()) for x in data_range.split(":")[0][1:].split("$") if x.strip()]
            y_values = [float(y.strip()) for y in data_values.split(":")[0][1:].split("$") if y.strip()]
            # Plot the data using matplotlib
            plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label=chart.Name)
       
    print('*********************')
    print('                     ')
            

xl = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(ef)
sh = wb.Sheets('Calc Tool')  
print(f'Processed sheet {sh.Name}')
for ch in sh.ChartObjects():
    series_output(ch.Chart)

# Add legends, labels, and show the plot
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X values')
plt.ylabel('Y values')
plt.show()

wb.Close(False)  # don't save & close workbook
xl.Quit()
```

You may need to adjust the data processing part based on the specific format of your data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution need to tweak the formatting but amazing work!

Comment: @1324241421 Your "thanks" would be more effective if you **accept** the answer (just click the check mark at the top left).

Comment: When you address a new user, look at their badges: no badges means the new user couldn't care less about learning the workings of the site. Then, you may decide that the question in itself is worth an answer (as it was the case here), but...